# How bad are minor power fluctuations for computers?

Tags: hardware-failure, power, ups, surge-protection

Whenever a large appliance or power-tool is turned on where I live, such as a refrigerator, vacuum, chainsaw or similar, light-bulbs will often dim down for a fraction of a second before returning back to normal brightness. This seems to be pretty commonplace, and is caused by appliances drawing a lot of power when starting up, causing a temporary drop in power elsewhere (possibly followed by a small surge as the power returns to normal).

As far as I can tell this is technically a brownout, which is supposedly really bad for computers, and it makes me wonder if I should be worried about leaving my desktop computer turned on when this happens. However, other than the lights dimming, I’ve yet to observe it having any ill effect on electronics: Computers, monitors, speakers, as well as charging smartphones/tablets, do not lose power and seem to be completely unaffected by it.

In my experience it is easy to find information about how power outages, lightning strikes, proper brownouts, etc., can cause damage to computers. However I’ve found it really difficult to get a clear picture on how this (much more common) type of power fluctuations affects hardware. Is it likely to cause damage in the long run, or is the hardware meant to withstand it? And is there any evidence for either of these claims?

Furthermore: If this is something that really needs protecting against, how much protection is good enough? Does a simple surge protector (such as [this one](https://www.brennenstuhl.com/en-DE/products/travel-adapters-adapter-plugs/primera-line-13.500a-surge-protected-adapter)) do the trick, or do you need something more advanced like an UPS? (Again, I’m wondering about this relative to the type of minor power fluctuations described above – whether a UPS or surge protector is a good idea in general is a different question altogether.)

Edit: I've monitored the internal voltages of the computer for a few days now, and they are really stable and always within 2% percent of their targets. Things like starting the fridge or wood chopper had no measurable effect on the voltages. I now feel at ease about the situation and I am very grateful for that.

Comment: There are really only two things that can kill electronics.  Exceeding the temperature tolerances of the device and unstable power (mostly lighting). A surge protector does not protect against a brown out, it protects against a lighting surge, hence the name "surge protector".  Electronics don't "age" or "wear out", typically, they will either last for their expected lifetime or fail within a relatively short timeframe.

Comment: Agree with Ramhound.   Also make sure (if you can) that your computer is on its own of lightly used circuit.

Comment: Also don't forget the possibility of a Batter Backup unit with a 6 - 8 millisecond transfer time to battery backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mitigate this you need to use a UPS.

However, the Computer uses 12v,5v,3.3v primarily.

Thus the power supply is going to take the brunt of these fluctuations.

If you bought a cheap $20 700w chinese or etc power supply it is NOT going to cope with these fluctuations and its going to pass them on to your computer components.

If you have a high quality power supply it should **nearly** completely isolate the components from the fluctuations.

Now each power supply has its tolerances for what it can handle so **YOUR MILEAGE WILL VARY**.

So it will affect your power supply the most.  Also most good power supplies have a voltage cut off, drop below say 90v and it shuts the power off automatically.

If your concern use a voltage monitor software or hardware on your 12v,5v, and 3.3v channel to see if the voltages go up or down during the conditions you mentioned.  And of course by what magnitude.  If the voltage drops below 5% then your out of specs and should probably consider a UPS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll be sure to watch for any changes in voltage using HWMonitor next time, and update the question about how it went. I have a couple of follow-up questions though:
1: So as long as the voltage does not drop below 5% then everything is fine; is there a similar upper limit?
2: Are these kinds of power fluctuations likely to reduce the lifespan of a power supply (provided that it is of decent quality, and is able to isolate the rest of the components from the fluctuations)?

Comment: @Bent the upper limit is also 5% so 11.4v to 12.6v, but obviously its supposed to be close to 12v.  Think of it like carpet, it will wear out eventually but garbage carpet may only last a couple years and decent might 10 years.  Buy some exotic premium brand 20 years.  Now it is unlikely you will get 20 years out of a power supply, the years here are examples of what might happen not exact numbers.